# Fix Character encoding of webpage using python Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to submit a form on this [page](http://mspc.bii.a-star.edu.sg/tankp/run_depth.html) using Mechanize.

```
br.open("http://mspc.bii.a-star.edu.sg/tankp/run_depth.html")
#selecting form to fill
br.select_form(nr = 0)
#input for the form
br['pdb_id'] = '1atp'
req = br.submit()
```

This however gives the following error

```
mechanize._form.ParseError: expected name token at '<! INPUT PDB FILE>\n\t'
```

I figure this is because of some misplaced character encoding[(ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036308/parse-error-while-using-mechanize-in-python). I would want to know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem are some broken [HTML comment tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp), leading to an invalid website which mechanize's parser can't read. But you can [use the included BeautifulSoup parser](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html) instead, which works in my case (Python 2.7.9, mechanize 0.2.5):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
br.open('http://mspc.bii.a-star.edu.sg/tankp/run_depth.html')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['pdb_id'] = '1atp'
response = br.submit()
```